# Heating degree days forecast

Tags: meteorology, open-data

I am trying to find heating degree days forecast data

1. for a certain state
2. for a long period ( > 3 mons)
3. published by the US government or universities.

What I found:

1. Heating Degree Days W. N. Central, Monthly by EIA.com. This one has forecast to 2018, but it forecast the entire W.N. Central region.
2. http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/analysis_monitoring/cdus/degree_days/hfstwpws.txt Here is a state-wide forecast, but it only forecast 7-day.

This 2 data don't meet all the requirements. I was wondering if anyone know data that would meet all the requirements?

Comment: So to verify/clarify... you want a current 3 month forecast, not 3 months of past forecasts??

Comment: For example, I want hearing days from 2018 Jan to 2018 March

Comment: Will say this... heating degree day forecasts into the future more than a week are going to be fairly poor forecasts.  The CPC issues forecasts for the likely temperature/precipitation pattern for the next 3 months (http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/predictions/90day/), but don't believe they've been shown to be that skillful.

Comment: There are also climate models such as the weekly ECMWF (http://www.ecmwf.int/en/forecasts/charts/mofcmulti/weekly-anomaly-extended-range-forecast) and CMC (http://theweathercentre.blogspot.com/2008/12/cmc-long-range-model.html). I don't think you'll find what you're looking for, as such forecasts wouldn't be very good.  If anyone makes such forecasts, I'd think i it'd probably be private companies hoping to make small gains in such a market.

Comment: One more clarification question, though: you want a forecast for each day... or just one forecast of the TOTAL for the January-March 2018 window?

Comment: I know long-term forecasting for temperature is hard, but I only want monthly heating degree days which would be easier than single-day temp forecasting.

Comment: The ideal data would total monthly heating degree days. For example, 3 data points for January-March 2018 window.